# fetching all the messages from AWS FIFO SQS

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, fifo

I am trying fetch messages from FIFO sqs queue. Here is the sample code:

```
import boto3

sqs_client = boto3.resource(
    'sqs',
    #aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    #aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name='us-east-2'
    )

queue_name = 'test_queue.fifo'

response = sqs_client.create_queue(
    QueueName=queue_name,
    Attributes={
        'FifoQueue': 'true',
        'ContentBasedDeduplication': 'true'
        }
        )


for i in range(0,50):
    status = response.send_message(MessageBody = 'This is test message #'+str(i), MessageGroupId='586474de88e03')

while True:
    messages = response.receive_messages(MaxNumberOfMessages=10)
    if len(messages)>0:

        for message in messages:
            print message.body

    else:

        print('Queue is now empty')
        break
```

but what I am getting is only the first 10 messages and then its showing "Queue is now empty" although I can see there are 40 available messages in the queue from AWS console.

So here I want to fetch all the messages from the queue in loop. Any lead would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a small number of messages in an SQS queue, especially an extremely small number as in your case, you may not get any messages returned and may need to retry the call:

> Short poll is the default behavior where a weighted random set of machines is sampled on a receive-message call. Thus, only the messages on the sampled machines are returned. If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested per receive-message call. **If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular receive-message response. If this happens, repeat the request**.

Also, generally speaking, once you receive a set of messages, you process them and then delete the messages that you processed - for testing purpose at least you may want to delete each returned message after each 'print message.body', and before you make the next receive request.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Isn't it possible to read the other messages while not deleting the previous ones which I have already received if I set the visibility timeout very high?

Comment: That's not the explanation in this case, @EJBrennan. A FIFO queue is designed to prevent out-of-order handling, so it will give you no more messages until you delete the ones you have already received.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if I have to delete a message after receiving it to get the next one, then what is the point of having a visibility timeout? Bit confused

Comment: Since HTTP/S is stateless, the "connection" doesn't tie messages to a specific consumer, and the visibility timeout keeps already-received messages hidden from all consumers for a sufficient period of time for a consumer to process the messages, eventually making them visible again if you failed/crashed/hung/etc. so that you or another consumer can retry.  A core assumption of a FIFO queue is that you are planning to process the messages in order and delete them when done, before asking for more. Re-read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Question :I want to fetch all the messages from the queue in loop.............. My answer :(read it completely) for fifo queue . Read that message then send that same message back to that queue and delete it from the queue .... It would be safe only if u do so(by proper exceptions hadlling and Message handler) . Try writing python programs with proper loggers and make it fail safe . Actually ur your is not fail safe .